# Chrome showing a different video controls bar for type video/quicktime

Tags: google-chrome, video, html5-video, quicktime

Anyone knows why Chrome is showing a different controls bar for a .mov file type video/quicktime (codecs: Timecode, Linear PCM, Apple ProRes 422 HQ) and how can I get it back to the default one?
Tried with a different .mov file (a QuickTime screen capture, different codecs) and it showed normally.

screenshot:

[image: 1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing the **audio controls** because Chrome only understands the audio part (codec) of your file. You can recreate the same issue by loading some file into an `<audio>` tag:

```
<audio controls> <source src="testfile.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"> </audio>
```

The problem happens because the ProRes video codec is not supported by Google's Chrome browser. The codec, created by Apple, only works in their Safari browsers (eg: Chrome did not license it from Apple).

**Solution:** 
Use a Chrome-supported **video codec** inside an MP4 / MOV / WebM video file. Options are: 
Use `.MP4` or `.MOV` with **H.264** and **AV1** codecs, or else use `.WEBM` with **VP8** or **VP9** codecs.